# 'Don't do as I do and...' meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

Let's say you're writing something along the lines of *don't do as I do and get a haircut*. Would this mean you got a haircut and you don't want readers to do the same, or you didn't get a haircut and you want readers to get a haircut?

Comment: It could be either. You’d need the context to disambiguate.

Comment: Clear it up with either "Don't do as I do; get a haircut" or "Don't do as I did -- I got a haircut."